# Double Quote on array value

Tags: php

```
{
  "test": {
    "stuId": "",
    "productdata": [
      "3:5:1-HGAR,5:6:custom product,5:4:Test Report"
    ]

  }
}
```

I have above json data, I need in `productdata` array each value should be quoted with double quote,

Ex: I have 3 value separated by comma but "" is in start and last only by default BUT i need all three value should be quoted with ""
output should be

```
{
  "test": {
    "stuId": "",
    "productdata": [
      "3:5:1-HGAR","5:6:custom product","5:4:Test Report"
    ]

  }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code with code block.

Comment: Show what you'r attemps

Comment: @invisal,formated

Comment: i need  below line   "3:5:1-HGAR,5:6:custom product,5:4:Test Report" out put should be    "3:5:1-HGAR","5:6:custom product","5:4:Test Report"

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess of your problem. You have JSON string.

```
$json_string = '{"test":{"stuId":"","productdata":["3:5:1-HGAR,5:6:custom product,5:4:Test Report"]}}';
```

Then, you can convert it to PHP object with `json_decode` and use `explode` to turn it to array and turn it back to JSON string.

```
$json = json_decode($json_string);
$json->test->productdata = explode(',', $json->test->productdata[0]);

var_dump(json_encode($json));
```

Comment: my problem is i need double quote on this line "3:5:1-HGAR,5:6:custom product,5:4:Test Report"  And out put should be "3:5:1-HGAR","5:6:custom product","5:4:Test Report"

Comment: @spb Try this it will do what you want

Comment: its working fine but can i achive this before converting to json.. 
                                  $request_params['test'] = [
                                        'stuId' => $inputParams['questiontype'],
                                        'productdata' => [$inputParams['metadatas']],
                                       
                  ]; productdata have this value .. "3:5:1-HGAR,5:6:custom product,5:4:Test Report"